# what is the difference between chdir(...) and system("cd ...")?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Was curious what the difference is in these two lines of code.

```
chdir ("..");
```

And

```
system ("cd ..");
```

Is there any difference other than call the system library function, which then calls chdir? At least, that's what I assume happens based on what I have found on the internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The first changes the current working directory of the current process. The second invokes a shell and executes the command in it, which changes *its* directory; the process's working directory is unchanged. The second is almost never what you want.